# Why is `mkdir ~root/.ssh` the same thing as `mkdir /root/.ssh`?

Tags: ssh, mkdir, tilde

This is fairly trivial and I'm just curious as to why `mkdir ~root/.ssh` is the same thing as `mkdir /root/.ssh`?  I'm reviewing the following docker file and the creator uses `mkdir ~root/.ssh` to create the `.ssh` directory:

https://github.com/macropin/docker-sshd/blob/master/Dockerfile

Is there any advantage to one over the other? When I first read it I assumed that `~root` would expand to `/rootroot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~USER` is just a shorthand notation for the home directory of user `USER`. For a normal user, this would typically be `/home/USER`, but for root, it is typically `/root`.

As for your question whether one is preferable to the other: The only difference is that `~root` gets expanded dynamically to root's home directory, whereas `/root` is an absolute path that does not undergo any expansion process. What you want depends on your particular use case. If you want your script to work on machines where root's home directory lies elsewhere than in `/root`, then use `~root`. If you want to make sure that the absolute path `/root` is always used, use `/root`.

In practice, it should not make any difference in most cases, though I would personally feel safer using `/root` unless I have reason to expect that my script will be run on machines where root's home directory is not `/root`.

Comment: How do you know that root's home directory is /root ? You said "but for root, it is /root" followed by "...on machines where root's home directory lies elsewhere than in /root"

Comment: Also, tilde expansion is not bash-specific; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01

Comment: [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixuseradmin/) and [Solaris 10](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E29492/userconcept-23283.html) both default to /; [Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54800/userconcept-23283.html#ADUSRuserconcept-20) appears to have moved to /root. [Linux FHS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/root.html)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, that was an unfortunate formulation. I meant *typically*. Thanks for the pointer, I improved my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol "~" is a special shortcut character that can be used to refer to your home directory.

`~root` will equal to the `root` users home directory, which is `/root`.
`~` represents the logged users home directory, and if you use `~user` it will return to you the `user`'s home directory.

Answer (score 1):

There's a distinct advantage to `mkdir ~root/.ssh` over `mkdir/root/.ssh` -- the former is flexible in its expansion of `~root` to your root user's *actual* home directory. What if you decided that you wanted your root user's home directory to be /root2 or /home/root or anything besides /root?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the other answers, it depends on where you intend to create the new directory. The form "mkdir /root/.ssh" unambiguously creates it at exactly that absolute path (assuming directory /root already exists and no other error).
However, since you intend to create the directory .ssh which is typically used to store information required by ssh, my take would be that you should prefer the other form "mkdir ~root/.ssh" because it (assuming no other error) creates the new directory .ssh exactly where its expected by the ssh command - in the root user's home directory, irrespective of where exactly it's located in the filesystem, and which need not be /root always, though it typically is.